# Json schema validation for property that can only be set once on an object inside an array

Tags: json, jsonschema

Is it possible to validate the json data below, so that "info" can only be filled in when "name" is "a" otherwise it must be empty or null?

```
[
  {
    "name": "a",
    "info": "this is mandatory"
  },
  {
    "name": "b",
    "info": "validation must fail"
  }
]
```

the JSONSchema

```
{
 "title": "Array of things",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "a",
          "b"
        ]
      },
      "info": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The json in an [online editor](https://mozilla-services.github.io/react-jsonschema-form/#eyJmb3JtRGF0YSI6W3sibmFtZSI6ImEiLCJpbmZvIjoidGhpcyBpcyBtYW5kYXRvcnkifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJiIiwiaW5mbyI6InRoaXMgc2hvdWxkIGZhaWwifV0sInNjaGVtYSI6eyJ0aXRsZSI6IkFycmF5IG9mIHRoaW5ncyIsInR5cGUiOiJhcnJheSIsIml0ZW1zIjp7InR5cGUiOiJvYmplY3QiLCJwcm9wZXJ0aWVzIjp7Im5hbWUiOnsidHlwZSI6InN0cmluZyIsImVudW0iOlsiYSIsImIiXX0sImluZm8iOnsidHlwZSI6InN0cmluZyJ9fX19LCJ1aVNjaGVtYSI6e319)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
{
 "title": "Array of things",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
   "type": "object",
   "properties":  {
      "name": {
         "type": "string",
        "enum": ["a", "b"]
      },
      "info" : {
         "type": ["string", "null"]         
      }
   },
   "required": ["name"],

   "oneOf": [
      {
         "properties": {
             "name": {"enum": ["a"] }
         },
         "required": ["info"]
      },
     {
         "properties": {
             "name": {"enum": ["b"] },
"info": {"enum": [null]}
         }         
      }
   ]
}
}
```

Comment: This will work for draft-4, but if the library you have uses a newer draft like draft-7, you can use if/then/else (if you want to). I won't add an answer as you've already accepted this one.